# Loading reflection models in mvc 3 razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reflection

I created a class from a database stored procedure using reflection and I want to be able to display the contents of the data table unto a razor view without using entities or having to create a strongly typed model for the class. Right now I'm doing the following:

```
public static List<object> GetPeople()
{
    DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetPersons();

    List<object> obj = MapDataTableToPerson(DataAccess.GetPersons());

    return obj;
}

private static List<object> MapDataTableToPerson(DataTable dt)
{
    List<object> returnClassObject = new List<object>();

    Type typeClass = CreateClassFromDT(dt);


    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeClass);

        foreach(string columnName in ColumnNames)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = typeClass.GetProperty(columnName);

            property.SetValue(obj, dr[columnName], null);
        }

        returnClassObject.Add(obj);
    }

    return returnClassObject;
}
```

I call GetPeople from the controller and pass unto a view, but I have no clue on how to get the values from the created class in Razor, if anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am curious to know why you do not want  a (model/ viewmodel )class to do this ?

Comment: The company I'm working for makes a great amount of changes unto databases and they don't want to recompile and publish again every time it changes.

Comment: If you are going to do this approach for a Large amount of places, It is going to be hard to read the code later. Invest some time now and save money and time

Comment: It won't be applied to a lot of places, but it will manage a few things. Performance isn't an issue and readability/mantainability isn't one so much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the DataTable model to the view and loop through the columns and rows. I don't think you need to use reflection, just get a DataTable from your database.

Comment: I had not even thought of this..., this makes a lot of sense, will pass it on to my project leader and ask him if this is better. Thank you.

Comment: Although for some strange reason one of the parameters isn't being passed correctly, but this is another issue altogether